# Singular Matrix and Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, matrix-rank

> Let $I$ be an identity matrix.
>
> If $I+A$ is a singular matrix (i.e. $I+A$ has at least one eigenvalue
>   being zero), then $\|A\|\geq 1$.

How does a zero eigenvalue of $I+A$ imply $\|A\|\geq 1$?

Comment: @carmichael561 Thanks. Let me edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $I+A$ is singular, then $(I+A)x=0$ for some vector $x$. In other words, $Ax=-x$, and hence $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. This implies $\rho(A) \geq 1$. Since [$\Vert A \Vert \geq \rho(A)$ for any norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Upper_bound), the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

The spectral mapping theorem gives
$$\sigma(I + A) = 1 + \sigma(A) = \{1+\lambda : \lambda \in \sigma(A)\}$$ so if $0 \in \sigma(I + A)$ then $-1 \in \sigma(A)$.

Hence there exists $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax = -x$.

We conclude

$$\|A\| \ge \frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|-x\|}{\|x\|} = 1$$